# How can I push to Array in Object from Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is my Schema in Model.

```
const applicantEvaluationSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    applicantIdx: Number,
    application: {
      comments: [
        {
          userIdx: Number,
          comment: String,
          createdAt: Date,
        },
      ],
      evaluations: [
        {
          userIdx: Number,
          point: Number,
        },
      ],
    },
    interview: {
      comments: [
        {
          userIdx: Number,
          comment: String,
          createdAt: Date,
        },
      ],
      evaluations: [
        {
          userIdx: Number,
          point: Number,
        },
      ],
    },
  }
);
```

I wanna push comment in application.comments

I got the idea that clone the Array, push my comment and update it

but I think There's the better way to push the object.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Model.update`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update) with the [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push) operator:

```
//Your model
ApplicantEvaluation.update(
  { /* selection criteria */ }, 
  {
    $push: {
      'application.comments': /* new comment object */
    }
  }
);
```

With the `$push` operator, you supply a field to push to and the new object. If you have a nested field, use dot syntax to access the field. Since the `comments` array is nested inside `application` use `'application.comments'`.